# C++ Accessing class variable from another class

Tags: c++, class

I have a class called MineData:

```
class MineData {
private:
    int row = 10;
    int col = 20;
public:
    MineData() {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> data (col, std::vector<int>(row, 0));
    }
}
```

and I have a class called Grid:

```
class Grid : public QWidget {
    MineData mineData;
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(mineData.data, this);
}
```

so I want to access the data variable in Grid class from MineData class, but when I do

```
mineData.data
```

I get an error:

> class 'MineData' does not have 'data' member

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the data variable is not a property  of MineData class instances. Add data variable as class's variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have currently declared `data` as a local variable in `MineData`'s constructor. Instead, you need to make it a member variable. Then, you can instantiate it in the initializer list.

```cpp
class MineData {
private:
  int row = 10;
  int col = 20;

public:
  vector<vector<int>> data;
  MineData(): data(col, vector<int>(row, 0)) { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector `data` needs to be added as a class field. Now it is constructed in the `MineData` class constructor as a temporary variable and it is removed after the constructor function is finished.

```
class MineData {
private:
    int row = 10;
    int col = 20;
public:
    MineData() {
        data.resize(col, std::vector<int>(row, 0)); 
    }
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data 
}
```